# What is Selenium WebDriver's default implicit wait value?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

What is Selenium WebDriver's default implicit wait value?

The selenium documentation says that it is "0" but when I call .findElement on a brand new project, where a element doesn't exist on the DOM, it seems to get a TimeoutException after a while rather than hang indefinitely.  Does "0" mean wait forever or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default value for implicit waits is indeed zero, which means (and always has meant) "fail `findElement` immediately if the element can't be found." You shouldn't be receiving a `TimeoutException` directly from `findElement`. You'll likely only be receiving that when using a so-called "explicit wait", using the `WebDriverWait` construct.

Comment: Thanks Jim.  I spent some time and created a unit test that proves it here: https://github.com/djangofan/simple-selenium-maven-template/blob/master/src/test/java/qa/test/selenium/tests/TestImplicitWaitDefaultTimeout.java

Comment: I still wish I knew where the line of code is, within the Selenium codebase, that shows the default is 0.  Do you know where that is?

Comment: lib\webdriver line 1353: `webdriver.Command(webdriver.CommandName.IMPLICITLY_WAIT).
          setParameter('ms', ms < 0 ? 0 : ms),
      `

Answer (score 1):

I believe, in SeleniumBasic at least, the implicit wait is 3000ms, or 3 seconds. You can find out for yourself by simply using msgbox(driver.timeouts.implicitwait()).