# Execution of script becomes very slow, after using size() <1

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium3

I have following code for checking whether the link is present in sideBar or not:

```
public void verifyLinkIsPresentOnSideBarOrNot() {
    if(driver.findElements(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("xpath of link"))).size() < 1)
        System.out.println("Now link is not present in sidebar");
    else 
        System.out.println("Now link is present in sidebar");
}
```

The code is working very fine, it also displays the correct result.

But the problem I am facing is as follows:

Whenever link becomes visible on screen, the message "Now link is present in sidebar" gets printed on the console immediately and script executes faster.

But whenever link becomes invisible in sidebar, "Now link is not present in sidebar" message takes lots of time to get printed on the console, and script execution becomes very slow.

I have not used any kind of waits and Thread.sleep(Time) in the code.
I have aslo tried isDispalyed(), isEnabled but getting wrong messages printed on console. I want above code only.

Any solution for this problem ?

Comment: Might be U have set Implicit wait somewhere, So it is taking longer time.

Comment: No, Arun as i have mentioned in the question, I have not used any wait, else part message gets printed immediately but if section message takes lots of time for printing the message, and script becomes lazy.

Comment: And same thing should happen with else section message also if i had used any waits, but selenium prints the message as fast as lightning.

Comment: [implicitlyWait](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) has nothing to do with Thread.Sleep! If you create a Firefox instance than he will set a default implicitlyWait value (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27831865/what-is-selenium-webdrivers-default-implicit-wait-value)) Explicitly set the implicitlyWait to 1sec to see if that is the problem